# DJANGO Iterar un un array (diccionario) enviado por POST y guardarlo en la db en views.py

Tags: array, django, post, bucles, diccionarios

Tengo un template que genera dinámicamente inputs (con js) cuyo name se almacena en un array. El usuario puede ingresar uno o más imputados con su nombre y situación.

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
numero = models.ForeignKey(Expediente, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank = False)
nombre_imputado = models.CharField('Nombre del Imputado', max_length = 255,  blank = False)
estado = models.CharField('Estado', max_length = 20, blank = False, choices = ESTADO_CHOICES)
```

El resultado final enviado por POST en la vista es algo así:

```
<input name="imputado[0][nombre_imputado]"      value="...">
<input name="imputado[0][estado]" value="...">
<input name="imputado[1][nombre_imputado]"      value="...">
<input name="imputado[1][estado]" value="...">
<input name="imputado[n][nombre_imputado]"      value="...">
<input name="imputado[n][estado]" value="...">
```

No puedo iterar ni acceder al elemento "imputado" de ninguna manera.
Estoy utilizando el modelo CreateView de Django.

Si imprimo los valores individuales sale correctamente. Es decir:

```
return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('imputado[0][nombre_imputado]'))
return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('imputado[0][estado]'))
```

Pero necesito iterarlo y guardarlo en la base de datos y no puedo lograrlo.

Soy nuevo en Django/python, en php me resultaba habitual este tipo de iteración y guarda en la base de datos pero en este caso luego de mucha lectura no logro captar la posible solución.

Mi template:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block titulo %}
    Expedientes | Crear imputados
{% endblock titulo %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
{% endblock extrahead %}

{% block body %}
<div class="card" >
    <div class="card-header">
        <strong class="card-title">Agregar imputados: Expediente Nro. {{ expedientes.numero }} caratulado "{{ expedientes.caratula }}"</strong>
    </div>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'repositorio:crear_imputado' expedientes.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="validarInput()" placeholder="Nombre del imputado" id="nombre_imputado">
                <select class="form-control" id="estado_imputado" maxlength="255">
                    <option value="Libre">Libre</option>
                    <option value="Detenido">Detenido</option>
                </select>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button onclick="crear_imputado()"  id="btn_Validar" class="btn btn-primary add-supplying-location-row" type="button" disabled>Agregar</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="listing-table">
            <div class="table-responsive sup-loc-table">
            <table class="table text-center" style="border-color:white;background:#138496;color:white;" >
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary  btn-sm" type="submit">Confirmar</button>
</div>
</div>

</form>


{% endblock body %}
{% block extrajs %}
<script>
    var n=0;
    function crear_imputado() {
      var nombre_imputado = $("#nombre_imputado").val();
      var estado_imputado = $("#estado_imputado").val();

      $('#nombre_imputado').val('');
      var supmarkup = "<tr class='text-center' style='vertical_align:middle;'>\
                <td style='padding:0.20rem;'>\
                    <input name='imputado["+ n +"][nombre_imputado]' value='"+ nombre_imputado +"' hidden><span>"+ nombre_imputado + "</span>\
                </td>\
                <td style='padding:0.20rem;'>\
                    <input name='imputado["+ n +"][estado]' value='"+ estado_imputado  + "' hidden><span>"+ estado_imputado  + "</span></td>\
                <td class='text-right' style='padding:0.20rem;'>\
                    <input type='button' style='margin-right:5%;' name='supplyingLocRecord[]' value='X' class='deletesupLoc btn btn-light'>\
                </td>\
            </tr>"

      $(supmarkup).hide().appendTo(".sup-loc-table table tbody").fadeIn(1000);
      n++;
    };

    $(document).on('click','.deletesupLoc',function(){
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    });
</script>
<script>
    function validarInput(){
        if(document.getElementById("nombre_imputado").value.length>0){
          document.getElementById("btn_Validar").disabled = false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("btn_Validar").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
{% endblock extrajs %}
```

[image: Ejemplo del template]

Comment: Adjunta todo el código de tu vista `CreateView` para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Perdón @JulioCesar por ahora no tengo código. He intentado con todo lo que encuentro pero no llego a ningún resultado.   Tampoco puedo acceder a los elementos del array "person" en forma individual, sin considerar otras keys (no arrays) enviadas por el método POST. Probé con      `for key in HttpResponse(request.POST.items()):     value = request.POST['person']` y el mensaje de error es: MultiValueDictKeyError at /(...)  . Te pido por favor si puedes ayudarme porque estoy estancado con este tema

Comment: En realidad estas respondiendo al cliente con texto, o lo que contenga `request.POST.get('person[0][name]')`, ni siquiera rederisas un template, necesito ver el código de la vista `CreateView`, para así ayudarte...

Comment: @JulioCesar Edité la pregunta y agregué el template. Tal vez esto ayude para entenderlo. Tal vez hay otra opción más adecuada para hacer esto. Básicamente mi idea es un template que envíe uno o más imputados con sus datos y se carguen en la tabla imputados siguiendo el modelo indicado. Como no sé si tiene 1,2 o más imputados tengo que hacer un template con carga dinámica para que pueda el usuario ingresar la cantidad que necesite.

Comment: @JulioCesar el conflicto lo tengo en el momento de recibir los datos enviados por post en mi vista. Estoy usando el modelo de CreateView pero tal vez no es lo mas conveniente. Perdòn por mis preguntas y gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @JulioCesar  https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0 Acà encontrè un tutorial interesante. Tratarè de llevarlo adelante y subir la soluciòn.